# SQL Server 2014 Restore DB only has "Verify Backup Media" option

Tags: sql-server-2014, restore

I just downloaded SQL Server 2014 Management Studio. I got the backup files ".bak" from my colleague. When I try to do a restore from "Database > Restore Database...", the window dialog only has "Verify Backup Media" instead of "OK", "Cancel", etc.

Clicking the button the message on top of the dialog stated "Backup media verified successfully", but the database is not restored.

Did I miss out any configuration during installation or perhaps user permission issue? I'm using "sa" user.

Comment: Any chance you could attach a screenshot perhaps?

Answer (score 1):

After lots of searching it seems abit hard to figure out why restoring database only has the "Verify Backup Media" option in my SSMS.

I tried "Restore Files and Filegroups..." but hit another error **"The backup set holds a backup of a database other than the existing"**, until I came to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43798703/2243398), writing the script instead to restore the ".bak" file works for me.

Answer (score -1):

Please check your screen resolution. Maybe your monitor is cropping restore backup screen becouse of low resolution. It simply does not fit in screen so you can not see the OK buttons.